# variable is losing the id when form is submitted

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I am trying to update news articles, I am getting the id from the url when the user clicks the update button, by using id = $this->uri->segment(3);, when the update button is clicked it loads a view called update. the problem I am encountering is the variable is not passing my id to the model because when I submit the form the id is no longer stored in the $id variable. any help would be mostly appreciated.

news controller

```
public function update() {


    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['title'] = 'Update a news item';
    $this->load->view('news/update');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {


    $this->News_model->update($id);
    redirect('News/index');

    }


}
```

news model

```
 public function update($id) {

        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);


         $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'text' => $this->input->post('text')
    );



     $this->db->where('id',$id);
     $this->db->update('news',$data);

 }
```

main news page

```
    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
    <p class="lead"><a href="<?php echo site_url('News/create'); ?>">Create Article</a></p>;
  </div>


 <?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>
 <h3><?php echo $news_item['title']; ?></h3>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"> <?php echo $news_item['text']; ?></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-2"><p><a href="<?php echo site_url('news/'.$news_item['id']); ?>">View article</a></p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-2"><p><a href="<?php echo site_url('News/update/'.$news_item['id']); ?>">update</a></p></div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2"><p><a href="<?php echo site_url('News/delete/'.$news_item['id']); ?>">Delete article</a></p></div>
    </div>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I think you have to keep the value of `$id` in a hidden field. And when form post collect that value and pass it to model!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using ->uri to get the URI segments? First segment is the controller name, second is the method name, any further segments, are passed into the method as input parameters. So redefine your update method to include the $id as the input parameter. And check immediately if the $id is set. If it's not, then your URL is not correct.

Comment: I am using $id = $this->uri->segment(3); because the news item id is taken from the url and then stored in the $id variable, if I pass the id in to the update method in the controller update($id) i get an error saying that the $id is undefined

Comment: Then your URL is not correct. Or you are fiddling with routes.

Comment: It disappears when I submit the form